# Windows can't allocate memory and stops the program?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   unsigned long maxindex = 2147483647ul+2ul;

   char* p = new char[maxindex];

   for(int i = 0; i < maxindex; i++)
   {
       p[i] = 65;
   }

   cout<<"Value at index "<<maxindex-1<<" is "<<p[maxindex-1]<<endl;

   delete[] p;

   return 0;
}
```

I'm running this program on a windows 64-bit with 4GB of memory. When I start running the program memory is at 0.99GB, memory usage goes up to 3.07GB then the program stops responding and I'm asked to close the program.

If I change `2ul` in `unsigned long maxindex = 2147483647ul+2ul;` to `1ul`, memory usage goes up to 2.98GB and the program runs successfully.

Why is this happening? It's only one more char element to allocate.

Comment: Print the value of `i`, too? Make sure it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Change `for(int i` to `for(unsigned long i`.

Comment: I tried it and it works. But why does the program work when I use 1ul and not 2ul using for(int i; ,2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648? 1ul shouldn't work too but it does.

Comment: Because you're using INT and not UNSIGNED INT in the for loop. That is what the answer is trying to tell you.. The int overflows into the negative range and you cannot allocate negative size..